# Convert object property name to attribute and property value

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have this c# object with me

```
public class UserRoleAndGroupData
{
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public int UserIntID { get; set; }
}
```

and would like to convert it in xml like this -

```
<add>
  <doc>
   <field name="RoleName">MyRole1</field>
   <field name="RoleID">123</field>
   <field name="UserIntId">567</field>
  <doc>
</add>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
UserRoleAndGroupData u = new UserRoleAndGroupData();
...
string template = $@"<add>
  <doc>
   <field name="RoleName">{u.RoleName}</field>
   <field name="RoleID">{u.RoleId}</field>
   <field name="UserIntId">{u.UserIntID}</field>
  <doc>
</add>";
...
```